# problem with connecting GPU with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have installed cuda, cudnn, conda, cuda drivers and tensorflow. Also, by the guide I have set system env paths and I was very careful to install compatible versions.

But still when I run in jupyter notebook part of code

```py
# Import TensorFlow into jupyter notebook
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
print("TF version: ", tf.__version__)
print("TF Hub version: ", hub.__version__)

# Check for GPU availability
print("GPU", "available (YESSSSSS!!!!!!!)" if tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU") else "not available :()")
```

I get info

```
TF version:  2.15.0
TF Hub version:  0.15.0
GPU not available :()
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: What graphic card are you running? are the drivers up to date or supported?

Comment: @yeshks Nvidia geforce 3060 12 gb is gpu, drivers are just installed ( latest version ) and I installed version for my pc configuration ( based on Nvidia identification form)

Comment: Kindly check the [Hardware and Software](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) requirements to install TensorFlow with GPU setup. Please install all the required software (Nividia GPU driver, CUDA and cuDNN) and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the same link to enable GPU support in your system